# Fetch the most recent N records from Elasticsearch using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to retrieve the last 50 records inserted into `Elasticsearch` to find out their average for an *Anomaly detection* project.
This is how I am retrieving data from ES. However, it is fetching the entire data, not the last 50 records. Is there any way to do that?

```
edf = spark \
   .read \
   .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
   .option("es.read.metadata", "false") \
   .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true") \
   .option("es.port","9200")\
   .option("es.net.ssl","false")\
   .option("es.nodes", "http://localhost") \
   .load("anomaly_detection/data")

# GroupBy based on the `sender` column
df3 = edf.groupBy("sender") \
     .agg(expr("avg(amount)").alias("avg_amount"))
```

Here the `sender` column is fetching the entire row data, how to get only the last 50 `DataFrame` rows data?

Input data schema format:

```
|sender|receiver|amount|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add the query while reading the data as

```
query='{"query": {"match_all": {}}, "size": 50, "sort": [{"_timestamp": {"order": "desc"}}]}'
```

and pass it as

```
edf = spark \
   .read \
   .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
   .option("es.read.metadata", "false") \
   .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true") \
   .option("es.port","9200")\
   .option("es.net.ssl","false")\
   .option("es.nodes", "http://localhost") \
   .option("query", query)
   .load("anomaly_detection/data")
```

Comment: Do I need to ingest a new `_timestamp` column like `sender`, etc. during Data Ingestion to ES?

Comment: Yes, it should be enable in the mapping, and should be date type.

Comment: Thanks, Shankar. I got pulled into some other work. WIll `Accept` if it helps.